# How to use binary data inside a python file

Tags: python, binary

I want to use a binary data of jpg file inside a py file.
I can use:

```
with open("example.jpg", "rb") as f:
     Content = f.read()
```

But in that case I have to use both jpg file and python file.

So I want to have that binary data included in python file as binary
I tried with triple-double quotes after getting binary by formatting jpg to txt and copying, but it """binary code""" is still a string.

Comment: Please add the code of what you have tried so far and create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your input and desired output.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you want to hardcode the image as a string inside Python, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to hardcode the image as a string in Python (read it once and copy the results as a string directly inside the Python code). For this, I suggest you use `base64`:

```
import base64

with open("yourfile.ext", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

That is a string you can print and save directly in your code. To turn it back into binary, just do the inverse with `base64.b64decode`.

Comment: Sorry for my question being unclear.

Comment: I want to save jpg file's binary code inside a python file

Comment: Photo_binary = "(jpg's binary)"
With open("new_image.jpg", "wb") as f:
f.write(Photo_binary)

#I want to use something like this to store #file's binary data so I wouldn't have to #have image file inside current working #directory and have file inside a py file